# Display Bitstreams in Google Docs Viewer

Tags: pdf, google-docs, dspace, bitstream

I've been embedding Google Docs Viewer in my DSpace instance, an online digital repository, using an iframe.

This is my site link: http://202.78.89.123:8081/xmlui/handle/123456789/145

DSpace generates bitstream links to each item/pdf in the repository. When I click the preview link, an iframe appears in my page but doesnt load any document. But when I change the source of my iframe to a pdf path file, which is publicly accessible in the world and not a bitstream, the viewer loads the document.

I have done everything I can, from checking whether my web server is publicly accessible by google docs viewer. My web server is publicly accessible and I suspect Google Docs Viewer doesnt anymore support bitstreams?If that's true then how will I display a pdf file in an iframe within my page? Any idea?

Below is my page that says "Apologies. There is no Preview Available"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why I cant display the bitstreams on my google docs viewer is that even though my IP is publicly accessible, my ports are private. What I did is, make the ports public by setting it on the router.